# How to resolve jbossews on openshift: Failed to execute: 'control restart'?

Tags: git, openshift

When I push my app at Openshift it was upload and final messages are

```
remote: Starting jbossews cartridge
remote: jbossews process failed to start
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
remote: Activation status: failure
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: 5433a24de0b8cd0dfa----- (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: 
Failed to execute: 'control start' for 
/var/lib/openshift/5433a24de0b8cd0dfa0000ec/jbossews)

remote: Deployment completed with status: failure
remote: postreceive failed
```

Also when I manually restart the application from Openshift website, it was showing me

```
"Unable to complete the requested operation"
"Starting jbossews cartridge
jbossews process failed to start
The jbossews cartridge is already stopped
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/5433a24de0b8cd0dfa-----/jbossews"
```

How would you troubleshoot this error message?

Answer (score 4):

This can happen because of a lot of different issues. You can try to check the log to see what's wrong:

```
rhc tail -a myapp
```

Answer (score 2):

The key error message is "`postreceive failed`": you need to check why your app doesn't deploy properly.

You'll find an example in [this thread](https://forums.openshift.com/deploying-war-file):

> Your project does not have the correct structure for a maven based project.
>   Try creating a jboss ews 2 gear, then `git clone` the files from there and check the structure.
>   If you want to use the `--from-code` option, it needs to have that structure. Including the `pom.xml` with the openshift profile.
>   You can browse the correct structure here:[origin-server/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews/template](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews/template).
>
> If you just want to bundle your application as a war file, and add it to the webapps dir, then you can delete the `src` directory and `pom.xml` files and do that.
>
> You should be able to easily move your project into the correct structure.

Comment: i already remove pom.xml and src folder. Still this was happening.

Comment: @MohanKumarBai I understand. Maybe have another look at the template project and see if you can deploy that (then modify it to include your own sources).

Comment: Why this is happening ? It is my application problem or configuration problem or openshift have this problem ?

Comment: I am upload by git bash command line. Can u tell me how i seen my details and file structure what i upload through git bahs command line.

Comment: @MohanKumarBai Great! What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I noticed a slight difference between [the template repo](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews/template) and my own.

First, I had not created a `webapps` folder with a `.gitkeep` in it.  Second, I needed Java 7 and had not created the file `.openshift/markers/java7`  (I had not realized Java 6 was used by default).

After doing both of these things, the deploy worked for me.